# meta теги для SEO оптимизации

Tags: html

Какие мета теги должны быть для правильной SEO оптимизации?

Comment: [вот здесь расписано и по полочкам разложено](https://yandex.ru/q/question/computers/kak_pravilno_zapolniat_metategi_li_teg_6ec772df/?utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=wizard&answer_id=cf6628ee-f0e8-434c-9803-4870517d3845)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сами теги:

`<title>Содержимое тега Title</title>`

`<meta name="description" content="Содержимое мета-тега Description" />`

`<meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow" />`

`<h1>Содержимое тега H1</h1>`

С подробным описанием и советами по применению можно ознакомиться [тут](https://seogio.ru/meta-tegi/)

Comment: Title, description, keywords - это основные, но их еще и правильно заполнить надо.